# Round-tripping JSON in PowerShell 5.1 results in HTTP error 400

Tags: json, powershell, api, rest

I'm grabbing a JSON payload from a REST API which I intend to modify and then send back. I convert the payload to an object using ConvertFrom-Json, manipulate it using .Remove(), and convert it back to JSON with ConvertTo-Json.

When I send the modified payload back to the API, I get a "(400) Bad Request." Thinking I screwed something up when modifying the payload, I removed that part of the code but still got the same error, even though I'm "just" converting the unmodified payload from and to JSON.

Sending back an unmodified payload should result in a "(422) UNPROCESSABLE ENTITY" and if I send the payload back without even converting from and to JSON that's the response I get from the API.

In this case the -Depth parameter isn't the culprit as far as I can tell (I've added -Depth 100 just to be sure). I also output the payload before the ConvertFrom-Json and after the ConvertTo-Json operations, and the output looks identical on screen.

If I copy the output after the modifications and conversions from and to JSON and then paste that as the body in a Postman call - where all the other parameters are the same as in my code - the API call works as expected.

Checking the API logs on the server only contains this error: "BadRequest: 400 Bad Request: Failed to decode JSON object: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xf6 in position 2976: invalid start byte"

This makes me think that the conversion changes the encoding of the string but I can't for the life of me figure out how that would be possible.

After a day and a half trying to get to the bottom of this I'm more than happy get any and all feedback on this problem. :)

**Edit:** This must work with PowerShell 5.1 as that's the only version I can safely assume is installed.

Thanks.

Comment: `ConvertTo-Json -EscapeHandling EscapeNonAscii`?

Comment: Try running a dev proxy like fiddler in the background when you run the script - you’ll be able to see the raw body of the HTTP request to confirm the if bytes being sent on the wire are correct or not…

Comment: @iRon I realize that I forgot to mention that this must work with PowerShell 5.1, my apologies. I'll update the post.

Comment: @mclayton The script is executed by an orchestration engine (Nutanix Calm) on a remote PSH host, so unfortunately my debugging options are limited.

Comment: I got a tip to use a mock API endpoint (Beeceptor) to see what I actually got after converting the payload and I found that PSH changes character formatting to “true” UTF-8, in this case it took an ‘ö’ and changed it to \u00f6, something that the API I'm using can’t handle.

I think that this behavior is how the conversion in PSH is meant to work, but since I'm not an authoritative source on the matter I don't want to post this as an answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this was to use PowerShell 7.2. I spent almost 2 days trying to work around the limitations of JSON conversions in Windows PowerShell 5.1 to no avail.

In PowerShell 6.2+ you can add an -EscapeHandling variable to ConvertTo-Json with the value of EscapeNonAscii that will convert any non ASCII characters back to Unicode.

The downside to this is that I now have to ensure that there is PowerShell 6.2+ on the servers I remote into, but that's easier to control and manage than the results of the API call.